# Finding special symbols in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to match special symbols at start, end and middle of a string?
I know, that I should use regex. For example I made a function:

```
    def check_word(word: str) -> bool:
        special_symbols = '()1234567890!?_@#$%^&*.,'
        e = re.match(special_symbols, word) # How to match symbols at end?
        m = re.match(special_symbols, word) # How to match symbols at middle?
        s = re.match(special_symbols, word) # How to match symbols at start?
        if e is not None:
             return True
        if m is not None:
             return True
        if s is not None:
             return True
        if e is not None and s is not None:
             return False
        if s is not None and m is not None:
             return False

print(check_word("terdsa223124")) # --> True
print(check_word("ter223124dsa")) # --> True
print(check_word("223124terdsa")) # --> True
print(check_word("223124terdsa223124")) # --> False
print(check_word("223124ter223124dsa")) # --> False
```

How to fill `re.match` so that printing was correct?

Comment: Use `re.search` instead

Comment: There's also no reason to have three separate cases here. Just use `re.search` once and that'll do it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I read about `re.search`. And if I understood correctly it returns the first matched value. And in my case `print(check_word("223124terdsa223124"))` will not give `False`

Comment: Is for the string `terdsa223124` m == True?

Comment: @MaximTitarenko False because m is for middle match

Comment: @AlTs, I see. Just edited my answer, it turned out rather unusual, but works  nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily implement it without regex based on arithmetic operations on booleans:

```
import itertools

def check_word(word):
    spec_symbols = '()1234567890!?_@#$%^&*.,'

    match = [l in spec_symbols for l in word]
    group = [k for k,g in itertools.groupby(match)]

    return sum(group) == 1


print(check_word("terdsa223124")) # True
print(check_word("ter223124dsa")) # True
print(check_word("223124terdsa")) # True
print(check_word("223124terdsa223124")) # False
print(check_word("223124ter223124dsa")) # False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import re
a = ["terdsa223124", "ter223124dsa", "223124terdsa", "223124terdsa223124"]
final_output = {s:any([re.findall('^[\d\W]+[a-zA-Z]+$', s), re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+[\d\W]+[a-zA-Z]+$', s), re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+[\d\W]+$', s)]) for s in a}
```

Output:

```
{'223124terdsa223124': False, '223124terdsa': True, 'terdsa223124': True, 'ter223124dsa': True}
```

Comment: Could u please explain what means `^[\d\W]+[a-zA-Z]+$`?

Comment: @AlTs `^[\d\W]+[a-zA-Z]+$` searches for your first condition, namely that the string starts with any numeric or non alphanumeric characters. `^[\d\W]+` searches for numeric or non alphanumeric characters at the start of the string, and [a-zA-Z]+$ will ascertain that the rest of the string to the end contains alphabetic characters.